# How to create .exe file of JavaFXML project including database

Tags: javafx-8

I have develop an application in javaFX using Java DB (Network).Now I want to create an .exe file and want to install into another system with database. so please help me how to create .exe file with database.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaFX packaging toolset for packaging executables is [documented in self-contained application section](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) of the JavaFX deployment guide.